maven release:prepare to update ${project.version} property reference to release version in dependencyManagement
I have a multi module project of which one of them is a pom module which manages the dependencyManagement which other projects leverage. Say, here is the structure of the project and I have common-parent pom's dependencyManagement & pluginManagement refer commonutils & buildutils modules version. I tried using ${project.version}, but the pom is released with ${project.version} and which is getting resolved to child project (projects which leverage) version.
 root
 |- buildutils (jar module)
 |- commonutils (jar module)
 |- common-parent (pom module)

I found the same issue on stackoverflow. I like the solution but when I tried I am facing the issue "The version could not be updated: ${artifact.version}". I tried using -X option but I don't get lot information on why its failing.
here are the plugin versions I used

org.apache.maven.plugins:org.apache.maven.plugins:3.0.1
org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.16.2


First why having a common-parent in a sub directory? You would like to create a kind of BOM file? Please show the pom files ... also which versions do you use? maven-release-plugin, all other plugins, Maven version and JDK version etc.?
